# How to set background color of lines in IndentLine?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, indentation, colorscheme, plugin-indentline

I'm trying to configure `Yggdroot/indentLine` to use the same background color as used in whatever color scheme I'm using, that is I'd like the gray parts to have the same color as the background. From various screenshots I assumed this somehow must be possible, but I couldn't find *any* option that would actually influence this color so far. Finally I'd also like to change the color of the characters themselves too, but nothing I tried influenced these either. (The options I played with commented out below.)

The `~/.vimrc` I used here was this:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
call plug#end()

"let g:indentLine_setColor = 0                  "doesn't seem to change anything
"let g:indentLine_defaultGroup = 'SpecialKey'   "doesn't seem to change anything
"let g:indentLine_color_term = 1                "doesn't seem to change anything
"let g:indentLine_color_term = 239              "doesn't seem to change anything
let g:indentLine_char_list = [' ', ' ', '.']    "works as expected

set expandtab
set tabstop=4
color default
```

[image]

Comment: If I don't use the `g:indentLine_char_list` setting, I get the background colour to be transparent/the same as the main background. That might be how the screenshots were taken, and the other behaviour might be a bug. I just tried this because I saw your question.

Comment: @Lizzan Thanks, that worked for me! Funnily I also now tried to reinstall everything afterwards and that seemed to help too, so maybe it was indeed just a bug.